# No suitable driver found for dbc:mysql://localhost:8080/kholofedb

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jdbc, mysql-connector

I have searched across the internet about this problem the whole of yesterdy... I am a beginner with JDBC, but the solutions provided here and other sites are not working for me.

I am using "`mysql-connector-java-5.1.18-bin.jar`" on Linux Mint 32 bit.. I am using Eclipse 3.8 ...I have installed mySQL-server and it is running ( I ran it using: `sudo service mysql start` )... at runtime I get this error

```
connecting to psysical database...


java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for dbc:mysql://localhost:8080/kholofedb
  at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:604)
  at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:221)
  at com.psybergate.database.SimbleCode.main(SimbleCode.java:21)
```

here is my source code:

```
package com.psybergate.database;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class SimbleCode 
{

    private static final String USER = "root" , PASS = "";


    public static void main(String ...args)
    {
        try {
            String connectionURL =       "dbc:mysql://localhost:8080/kholofedb";
               Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        //  Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");
            System.out.println("connecting to psysical database...");
            Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionURL  , USER , PASS);

            Statement statement = conn.createStatement();
            System.out.println("Connection has been made");

            Scanner keyBoardScanner =  new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.println("Enter table name:");
            String tableName = keyBoardScanner.nextLine();

            System.out.println("Creating table...");
            statement.executeQuery("create table " + tableName + " (name , age ,salary)");
            System.out.println("Table successfully created");
            System.out.println("Inserting data into the table ...");
            statement.executeUpdate("insert into " + tableName + "values (kholofelo , 21 , 9969696)");
        }
        catch (ClassNotFoundException | SQLException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
```

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your connection URL should start with "jdbc:" not "dbc:"

Comment: ` Communications link failure

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
 at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0`

Answer (score 1):

Your connection string should be:

```
String connectionURL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:8080/kholofedb";
```

Comment: now I fixed that, but I am getting another exception which I also encountered when I was using postgresql

Comment: what exception? please check your port if it is 8080 or 3306.

Comment: I am getting this exception after fixing it:

Communications link failure

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
 at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
 at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
 at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:525)
 at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java.

Comment: The default port of mysql is 3306.

Maybe it's better to try this:
String connectionURL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/kholofedb";